# ¿Cómo realizar consulta a campo con formato JSON y obtener todos sus items?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla y en ella un campo de tipo VARCHAR(MAX) en el cual se guardan datos en formato JSON

¿Cómo  puedo hacer una consulta y que estos se devuelvan en una o varias columnas?
o insertarlos en una tabla temporal para luego ejecutar la consulta ¿?

Ejecuto esta pero no me sirve por que me devuelve el valor solo del primer ítem, necesitó obtenerlos todos. Debido a que la sub-consulta devuelve mas de una fila

```
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName, Email,
    (SELECT TOP 1 [Key] FROM OpenJson(IndustryMainSector) WITH ([Key] varchar(100))) AS Id,
    (SELECT TOP 1 [Value] FROM OpenJson(IndustryMainSector) WITH ([Value] varchar(100))) AS Industria
 FROM CompanyProfile
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

El formato dentro de la columna:

```
[{"Key":"1867","Value":"Home Supplies, Garden & Construction Materials"},
 {"Key":"298948","Value":"Indumentaria, Textiles y Accesorios, Servicios Comerciales y Profesionales"}, 
 {"Key":"301782","Value":"Business and Professional Services, Distribution lists"} ]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que lo que necesitas es utilizar APPLY para obtener los datos que quieres.

```
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName, Email,
    [Key] AS Id,
    [Value] AS Industria
 FROM CompanyProfile 
CROSS APPLY OpenJson(IndustryMainSector) WITH ([Key] varchar(100), [Value] varchar(100))
```